# wait gif on export

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django

I have a Django application with some statistics graphs that I show to user.
I have also an export option for these graphs.
When I click the export button, I create csv on the server and return it to client, so the file starts to download immediately. 
It all works great but creating csv takes time and I would like to show some "Wait..." gif till the file starts to download. What is the best way to do it?
(I don't want to create temp file link and go to that link after getting ajax response.)
My django view returns:

```
response = HttpResponse(open("statistics.tar.gz").read(), content_type='application/tar.gz')
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=statistics_%s.tar.gz' % str(get_customer_date(request.customer, datetime.utcnow())).split(" ")[0]
response['Content-Length'] = os.path.getsize("statistics.tar.gz")
response.set_cookie("export_download", value='download')
return response
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create an invisible iframe to be the target of the link. And onClick on that link, show the gif. Hide it when iframe stops loading :)

something like this (never tested, but should work in theory):

```
$("a#download-link").click(function(){
  $("#loading-div").show();
  $("body).append('<iframe id="myIframeId" ...>');
  $('iframe#myIframeId').attr('src', url);
  $('iframe#myIframeId').load(function() { $("#loading-div").hide(); });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Can you explain what exactly do you mean? (Can you show some code example or give some link where to read about it)

Comment: Hi. It still doesn't work for me since the load event is not triggered for some reason.

Comment: you could try `$('iframe#myIframeId').ready(function() { ... });` instead